# Find and modify text

Tags: notepad++

I have a text document with following structure:

```
Abies alba 13
Acer campestre 15, 16, 17, 21
Acer negundo 2
Achillea millefolium 20, 21, 26
Achillea ptarmica subsp. ptarmica 4, 10, 11, 26
...
```

The first part is a species name which is followed by codes. I want to separate these two parts, now separated only with space, using a separator (let it be `;`) with help of Notepad++. I tried to use the Replace toolbox with `Find what: \l \d`, which well determines the part which is to be modified. I need to preserve the letter and the digit, only to add the separator between them, however, I didn't find a way how to do that. Repeating the same command in the `Replace with:` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=[a-z])(?= \d)`
- Replace with: `;`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=[a-z])      # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a letter before
(?= \d)         # positive lookahead, make sure we have a digit after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]